# Send Data from Server to Client Python 2.7

Tags: python, server

I am trying to write a server that reads a .pdf file and sends the data to a client server.

Here is a snip of my server program.

```
while True: # infinite loop to connect to a client
    client, address = server.accept()
    data = copyfile(path)
    data = str(data)
    client.send(data.encode('utf-8'))
    client.close()
```

Here is a clip of my client source code:

```
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
# assume my host and ports are correct
client.connect((host, port))
data = client.recv(1024)
s = data.decode('utf-8')

print s

client.close()
```

Here is the error I am gettting:

client.send(message.encode('utf-8'))

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just send straight bytes.

```
#client.py
x = open('out.pdf','wb')
while 1:
    data =''
    data = s.recv(1024)
    if data == b'': break
    x.write(data)
x.close()
```

Server Code:

```
#server.py
x=open("test.pdf","rb")
client, address = s.accept()
while 1:
    data = x.read(1024)
    if data == b'':
        print("finished")
        x.close()
        client.close()
        break
    client.send(data)
```

Comment: Thanks. I had the idea of sending bytes because each data is just a bunch of zeros and ones.

Comment: I finally finished my GUI application for my class. I then packaged it. The app works, but I have to click the icon for it to show the window. I am on a mac.